# how to print all my data from hashmap to my textarea

Tags: swing, hashmap, append, textarea

how to print all my data from hashmap to my TextArea

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

    data.put("nama", "Yudi Setiawan");     
    data.put("kelas", "TI A MALAM");     
    data.put("hobi", "Programming");
```

` 
i want this all key and value  to append in my textarea

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like

```
for (String key : data.keySet()){
    System.out.println(key + data[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over your HashMap:

```
public static void printMap(Map mp) {
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you remove elements from the map?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your map, use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build the string with all the keys and values, and then store the result in your `JTextArea`.

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for (String key : data.keySet()) {
    str.append(key)
       .append("=")
       .append(data.get(key))
       .append("\n");
}
textArea.setText(str.toString);
```